# I am having errors with CS50 Finance problem in registration process

Tags: python, flask, cs50

The error is ":( registering user succeeds" and ":(  registration rejects duplicate username"

The detailed error log mentions that there is no table such as 'stock found'
Other registration processes have green ticks.

Can someone please help out with this code?

Here is my registration code in application.py

```
    @app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""

    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("Oh dear, give us the username!")

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("You have to give us password!")

        elif not request.form.get("confirmation"):
            return apology("You have to confirm your password!")

        # Ensure confirm password is correct
        elif request.form.get("password") != request.form.get("confirmation"):
            return apology("Oops, your passwords don't match up!")

        # Insert user and hash of the password into the table
        newuser = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (:username, :hash)",
        username=request.form.get("username"),
        hash=generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password")))

        if not newuser:
            return apology("Someone else swiped right on this Username, try a new one!")

        # Query database for username
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username",
            username=request.form.get("username"))

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect(url_for("index"))

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("register.html")
```

I have also given below the index code below - for the error with 'stock' table

```
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""

    # Query infos from database
    rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE user_id = :user",
                          user=session["user_id"])
    cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :user",
                          user=session["user_id"])[0]['cash']

    # pass a list of lists to the template page, template is going to iterate it to extract the data into a table
    total = cash
    stocks = []
    for index, row in enumerate(rows):
        stock_info = lookup(row['symbol'])

        # create a list with all the info about the stock and append it to a list of every stock owned by the user
        stocks.append(list((stock_info['symbol'], stock_info['name'], row['amount'], stock_info['price'], round(stock_info['price'] * row['amount'], 2))))
        total += stocks[index][4]

    return render_template("index.html", stocks=stocks, cash=round(cash, 2), total=round(total, 2))
```

HTML for register

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Register
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/register" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="confirmation" placeholder="Confirm password" type="password">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

HTML for Index

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Stocks
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Symbol</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Shares</th>
          <th scope="col">Price</th>
          <th scope="col">Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    {% for stock in stocks %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ stock[0] }}</th>
        <td>{{ stock[1] }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock[2] }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock[3] }}</td>
        <td>{{ stock[4] }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Cash</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ cash }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"></th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ total }}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score -1):

Before `Insert user and hash of the password into the table`, do `SELECT on the request.form.get("username")`, to see if the username already exists. Then if something is returned, return an error message.  I think that should solve the problem.